# How do I check if a row contains a certain string from a list of words

Tags: python, regex, string, pandas

```
for i in range(len(ingName)):
    x = ingName[i]
    #check if the string contains IngName ignoring uppercase Sub_Seg_Sub_Cat
    df = df_grocery[df_grocery['Sub_Seg_Sub_Cat'].str.contains(str(ingName[i]), case=False)]
    df['IngredientName'] = ingName[i]
    df['IngredientID'] = ingID[i]

    #write it out to a csv
    df.to_csv("ingred11.csv",  mode = 'a', encoding='utf-8', header=None)
```

What is the best way to check if a row in a column contains certain words? I am using str.contains and it is getting the substring. I want it where it checks if sauce is present in pasta sauce, not if sauc is present in pasta sauce, currently this is what it does, and is there anyway to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Hey @Andy Hayden, Thank you, but if I type in 
s = pd.Series(["cat dog", "dog", "sheep"]) s.isin(["cat", "dog"]) but I want it to be able to know its true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are after?

```
s = pd.Series(["cat dog", "dog", "sheep"])

# check if 'cat' or 'dog' is present in the Series.
s.apply(lambda x: np.max(np.in1d(np.asarray(x.split()), ['cat', 'dog'])))
Out[785]: 
0     True
1     True
2    False
```

Comment: Absolutely, Thank you, i voted your answer but i decided to go through another route yesterday to work with the files i was working with, but i will save this, and come back to it because i might be needing it soon.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) method:

```
In [11]: s = pd.Series(["cat", "dog", "sheep"])

In [12]: s.isin(["cat", "dog"])
Out[12]:
0     True
1     True
2    False
dtype: bool
```

Comment: if I type in this it says false
s = pd.Series(["cat dog", "dog", "sheep"])    
s.isin(["cat", "dog"])
but I want it to be able to know its true

Comment: @AbifoluwaOni I don't understand what you mean. The first row is True because `"cat"` is in `["cat", "dog"]`...